# How to model BMX spin back tuff shape

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model this shape here which is a BMX tuff, I started off with circle and also 2nd attempt a cylinder. The result is not good. So I wanted to know what would be the best approach for this.

[image]

Comment: You can either give your topology more cuts to make subdiv work better or you can use Shift+E on certain edges to make it "sharper" but not too much

Comment: just give more segments to blades along with support loops.
also bevel the corner edges